# How can i parse some strings from one block of text in an HTML file?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have this code:

```
public static void CreateTextList(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text;

            text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }
            TextList = Filters.filterNumbers(text);
        }
```

Filepath is for example: `d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html`

Now the block in this case of text I want to extract from the HTML is this:

```
<body onmousemove="overhere()">
<a  onmouseover="EnterContent('ToolTip','אבו זוהרי: &rsquo;&rsquo; בשעות הקרובות הפתעה לישראל &rsquo;&rsquo;','<u><span style=color:#000099;>כתב: כוח הימין   בתאריך: 11.07.14  שעה: 17:41</span></u><br>איום של הדובר הזרוע הצבאית של החמאס אבו זוהרי לקראת השבת:<br>&quot; בשעות הקרובות נכניס אלמנטים חדשים ללחימה שיגרמו לתושבי ישראל להתבלבל &quot;<br><br...'); Activate();" onmouseout="deActivate()" href="javascript:void(0)"> 
<img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/hot_icon_news.gif" border="0"></a></TD><TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="55%">
<FONT CLASS='text15bn'><FONT FACE="Arial">
<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116347&forum=scoops1"><b>
```

Now the way I am doing it it is extracting only the text: `בשעות הקרובות הפתעה לישראל`

But now I want to extract from the block another 2 parts:

```
First this part: בתאריך: 11.07.14  שעה: 17:41 
Seconde this part: http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116347&forum=scoops1
```

And add them to the List text too.
So in the end in text I will see in the first 3 indexes:

```
אבו זוהרי: בשעות הקרובות הפתעה לישראל
בתאריך: 11.07.14  שעה: 17:41
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116347&forum=scoops1
```

Then in the next loop iteration again index 3 4 5 also same extraction of the text part the date time part and the link part.

EDIT

Tried Corey solution. In top of the class i did:

```
string t = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Now t contain the content of the html file.
Then in the bottom i did:

```
// Combined regular expression pattern
            var pattern = @"&rsquo;&rsquo;(.*?)&rsquo;&rsquo;.*?([^\s]*?:\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+[^\s]+:\s\d+:\d+).*?<a href=""(http://.*?)""";
            // The 'SingleLine' option lets us work across the whole text
            var re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            // Run the RE against the source
            var m = re.Match(t);
            // Combine the capture groups into a string 
            string result = string.Join("\n", new string[] { m.Groups[0].ToString(), m.Groups[1].ToString(), m.Groups[2].ToString() });
```

And what i get in result is:

```
&rsquo;&rsquo;ל במבצע &rsquo;&rsquo;צוק איתן&rsquo;&rsquo; יומן מלחמה -היום החמישי.','<u><span style=color:#000099;>כתב: ש_ש   בתאריך: 12.07.14  שעה: 11:06</span></u><br>אשכול מרכזי לפעילות צה&rsquo;&rsquo;ל במבצע &rsquo;&rsquo;צוק איתן&rsquo;&rsquo; יומן מלחמה -היום החמישי.  <br> <br>      <br>מבצע &quot;צוק איתן&quot; נ...'); Activate();" onmouseout="deActivate()" href="javascript:void(0)"> 
<img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/hot_icon_general.gif" border="0"></a></TD><TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="55%">
<FONT CLASS='text15bn'><FONT FACE="Arial">
<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116498&forum=scoops1"
ל במבצע 
בתאריך: 12.07.14  שעה: 11:06
```

And what i should get is:

```
אבו זוהרי: בשעות הקרובות הפתעה לישראל
בתאריך: 11.07.14  שעה: 17:41
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116347&forum=scoops1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much exactly what Regular Expressions are for.

Each of the pieces of text you want to extract can be identified in context by a regular expression that matches just that piece and no more.  These are the regular expressions I came up with based on the HTML sample above:

```
&rsquo;&rsquo;(.*?)&rsquo;&rsquo;
([^\s]*?:\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+[^\s]+:\s\d+:\d+)
<a href=""(http://.+?)""
```

Each of those matches one of the output lines you specified, and does so uniquely in the example you supplied.  They may need a bit of tweaking to match other bits of text, but hopefully not too much.  The `()` characters enclose the text you are actually interested in, and the stuff outside that identifies the surrounding text.

You could run each of those regular expressions against the HTML source and probably get the output you're expecting.  If however there are other links in the file, or you want to make sure that all three of the items are present in the correct order, you can collapse the three into a single regular expression.  This will not match if any of the items is missing or malformed, only if all three terms match text on the page in the order supplied.

Here's the code:

```
// Combined regular expression pattern
var pattern = @"&rsquo;&rsquo;(.*?)&rsquo;&rsquo;.*?([^\s]*?:\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+[^\s]+:\s\d+:\d+).*?<a href=""(http://.*?)""";
// The 'SingleLine' option lets us work across the whole text
var re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
// Run the RE against the source
var m = re.Match(html);
// Combine the capture groups into a string 
string result = string.Join("\n", new string[] { m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3] });
```

There are a few other ways to do it if your requirements aren't for all pieces in the order given, but since you're processing a web page it's likely that this is going to be fairly consistent.

---

One word of warning: regular expressions are easy to get wrong.

There's an old saying:

> Some people, when faced with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."
>
> Now they have two problems.

And generally it's true.  The regular expressions I've written above do work for the example you've given, but may fail - or worse, give the wrong results - depending on the true content of the page.  Make sure you understand what they're doing, what their limitations are, and how they can go wrong before you decide to actually use this solution for anything like production code.  It'll save you grief in the long run.

Comment: Corey i tried your solution. On this line var m = re.Match(filePath); filePath contain a directory of the html file: d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html and in the string result line i got errors so i had to add after each Groups ToString(): string result = string.Join("\n", new string[] { m.Groups[0].ToString(), m.Groups[1].ToString(), m.Groups[2].ToString() }); but in the end i get in result just: \n\n    thats it.

Comment: Can't use the file's path for this, you have to use the content: `string htm1 = File.ReadAllText(filePath);`

Comment: Corey right i did. And updated my question with what i did and what i get.

Comment: oops... the Groups you want are 1, 2 and 3.  Group 0 will give you all of the text matched by the complete regular expression, not just the capture groups.  Fixed the code... try it again.

Comment: Corey the date time and link are ok but the text is not: ח פאיז אבו עיטה 
בתאריך: 12.07.14  שעה: 12:34
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=116521&forum=scoops1

Comment: The text should be: אבו זוהרי: בשעות הקרובות הפתעה לישראל and not ח פאיז אבו עיטה this ח פאיז אבו עיטה is somewhere in another place in the html file content nothing to do with the text in this case. In this case and then in all other cases i need to use a loop to find all places in the html file to parse/extract/get the text,date&time,link. The same format i show in my question.

Comment: Corey i forgot to mention that im using a loop for loop and i need to find all the places in the html file with this block and extract from it each time 3 items: the text the time&date and the link just like i show in my question.

Comment: Use the `Matches` method to find them all at once.